# Why isn't my Struct retrieving the right information via dot notation in C?

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to write a program where it takes the X-Y Coordinates and Radii of 2 Circles from the User. Then, it would determine if the 2 Circles intersect or is contained in one another.

For the contain() function, when I tried printing out the values of c1.x and c2.x, only c1.x appears to give me the user input while c2.x prints out a very large number that has no meaning for me. Why can't I retrieve my user input for c2.x? Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct circle {
    double radius;
    double x;
    double y;
};
// Returns 1 if the Circle intersects
int intersect(struct circle c1, struct circle c2);
int contain(struct circle *c1, struct circle *c2);

int main(){
    struct circle c1, c2;
    int answer, selection;
    do{
        printf("Please choose a Function to be used!!!\n");
        printf("1: Enter the Parameters of the 2 Circles:\n");
        printf("2: intersect():\n");
        printf("3: contain():\n");
        printf("4: Quit!!\n");
        scanf("%d", &selection);
        switch(selection){
            case 1:{
                // First Circle
                printf("Please Enter the Radius, X-Coordinate and Y-Coordinate of the First Circle\n");
                printf("Radius:\n");
                scanf("%d", &c1.radius);
                printf("X-Coordinate:\n");
                scanf("%d", &c1.x);
                printf("Y-Coordinate:\n");
                scanf("%d", &c1.y);
                // Second Circle
                printf("Please Enter the Radius, X-Coordinate and Y-Coordinate of the Second Circle\n");
                printf("Radius:\n");
                scanf("%d", &c2.radius);
                printf("X-Coordinate:\n");
                scanf("%d", &c2.x);
                printf("Y-Coordinate:\n");
                scanf("%d", &c2.y);
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                int choice = intersect(c1, c2);
                switch(choice){
                    case 1:{
                        printf("The 2 Circles intersects!\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2:{
                        printf("The 2 Circles does not intersects!!\n");
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                answer = contain(&c1,&c2);
                if(answer == 1){
                    printf("Circle C1 contains Circle C2!!\n");
                }
                else{
                    printf("Circle C1 does not contain Circle C2!!\n");
                }
            }
        }
    } while (selection < 4);

    return 0;
}


int intersect(struct circle c1, struct circle c2){
    // Calculate the Distance between the Centers of 2 Circles
    double xDiff, yDiff, dist, dRadii;
    xDiff = pow(c1.x,2) - pow(c2.x,2);
    printf("X Coordinate of C1 and C2: %d, %d\n", c1.x,c2.x);
    printf("%d", xDiff);
    if(xDiff < 0){
        xDiff = -xDiff;
    }
    yDiff = pow(c1.y,2) - pow(c2.y,2);
    if(yDiff < 0){
        yDiff = -yDiff;
    }
    dist = sqrt(xDiff + yDiff);
    dRadii = c1.radius + c2.radius;
    if((dist == dRadii) || (dist < dRadii)){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int contain(struct circle *c1, struct circle *c2){
    double specialValue;
    double xDiff, yDiff, dist, dRadii;
    xDiff = pow(c1->x,2) - pow(c2->x,2);
    if(xDiff < 0){
        xDiff = -xDiff;
    }
    yDiff = pow(c1->y,2) - pow(c2->y,2);
    if(yDiff < 0){
        yDiff = -yDiff;
    }
    dist = sqrt(xDiff + yDiff);
    specialValue = dist + c2->radius;
    // Checking
    if((c1->radius > specialValue) || (c1->radius == specialValue)){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't you get some warning from your compiler for this: `scanf("%d", &c1.radius);`? You tell `scanf` to parse an integer and store in memory that holds an `int` but the memory is actually used by a `double`. Half of the variable will not be written to at all and the format will not match as well. For `double` you must use `%lf` as format specifier.

Comment: You should also check the return value of `scanf`. If you enter something like `12.34` there will be a `.` pending in the buffer as `%d` does only consume decimal digits. In this case `scanf` will return `0` indicating an error immediately. Don't miss that opportunity.

Comment: @Gerhardh Ohh I see!!! No I didn't get an error from my compiler, I had mistakenly believed integers to be %i and doubles to be %d. Thank you for letting me know!!

Comment: But what do you mean by there will be a ```.``` pending in the buffer?

Comment: Then you should increase warning level. For GCC you can do this via `-Wall -Wextra`. And you should treat warnings as errors, too.

Comment: You enter a `.` and that does not match a valid character for integers. Therefore `scanf` will stop before that `.`. E.g. if you enter `12.34`, then `scanf("%d", &xy)` will only consume `12` and leave `.34` in input buffer. That will never be removed if you only parse integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems with argument passing for the `intersect` function and some other problems with the format specifier for `printf`.

Try something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct circle {
    double radius;
    double x;
    double y;
};
// Returns 1 if the Circle intersects
int intersect(struct circle *c1, struct circle *c2);
int contain(struct circle *c1, struct circle *c2);

int main(){
    struct circle c1, c2;
    int answer, selection;
    do{
        printf("Please choose a Function to be used!!!\n");
        printf("1: Enter the Parameters of the 2 Circles:\n");
        printf("2: intersect():\n");
        printf("3: contain():\n");
        printf("4: Quit!!\n");
        scanf("%d", &selection);
        switch(selection){
            case 1:{
                // First Circle
                printf("Please Enter the Radius, X-Coordinate and Y-Coordinate of the First Circle\n");
                printf("Radius:\n");
                scanf("%lf", &c1.radius);
                printf("X-Coordinate:\n");
                scanf("%lf", &c1.x);
                printf("Y-Coordinate:\n");
                scanf("%lf", &c1.y);
                // Second Circle
                printf("Please Enter the Radius, X-Coordinate and Y-Coordinate of the Second Circle\n");
                printf("Radius:\n");
                scanf("%lf", &c2.radius);
                printf("X-Coordinate:\n");
                scanf("%lf", &c2.x);
                printf("Y-Coordinate:\n");
                scanf("%lf", &c2.y);
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                int choice = intersect(&c1, &c2);
                switch(choice){
                    case 1:{
                        printf("The 2 Circles intersects!\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2:{
                        printf("The 2 Circles does not intersects!!\n");
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                answer = contain(&c1,&c2);
                if(answer == 1){
                    printf("Circle C1 contains Circle C2!!\n");
                }
                else{
                    printf("Circle C1 does not contain Circle C2!!\n");
                }
            }
        }
    } while (selection < 4);

    return 0;
}


int intersect(struct circle *c1, struct circle *c2){
    // Calculate the Distance between the Centers of 2 Circles
    double xDiff, yDiff, dist, dRadii;
    xDiff = pow(c1->x,2) - pow(c2->x,2);
    printf("X Coordinate of C1 and C2: %lf, %lf\n", c1->x,c2->x);
    printf("%lf\n", xDiff);
    if(xDiff < 0){
        xDiff = -xDiff;
    }
    yDiff = pow(c1->y,2) - pow(c2->y,2);
    if(yDiff < 0){
        yDiff = -yDiff;
    }
    dist = sqrt(xDiff + yDiff);
    dRadii = c1->radius + c2->radius;
    if((dist == dRadii) || (dist < dRadii)){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int contain(struct circle *c1, struct circle *c2){
    double specialValue;
    double xDiff, yDiff, dist, dRadii;
    xDiff = pow(c1->x,2) - pow(c2->x,2);
    if(xDiff < 0){
        xDiff = -xDiff;
    }
    yDiff = pow(c1->y,2) - pow(c2->y,2);
    if(yDiff < 0){
        yDiff = -yDiff;
    }
    dist = sqrt(xDiff + yDiff);
    specialValue = dist + c2->radius;
    // Checking
    if((c1->radius > specialValue) || (c1->radius == specialValue)){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

}
```

For further questions, please add a demo user input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct circle {
    double radius;
    double x;
    double y;
};
```

Here , members of structure is of double data type. So you have to use %lf instead of %d which is format specifier for integer.

Do this in main():

```
                scanf("%lf", &c1.radius);
                printf("X-Coordinate:\n");
                scanf("%lf", &c1.x);
                printf("Y-Coordinate:\n");
                scanf("%lf", &c1.y);
                // Second Circle
                printf("Please Enter the Radius, X-Coordinate and Y-Coordinate of the Second Circle\n");
                printf("Radius:\n");
                scanf("%lf", &c2.radius);
                printf("X-Coordinate:\n");
                scanf("%lf", &c2.x);
                printf("Y-Coordinate:\n");
                scanf("%lf", &c2.y);
```

In intersect() :

```
 printf("%lf", xDiff);
```